# Generates an error, while adding an API to Ready API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, ready-api

I am trying to add an API in ReadyAPI, its generated the following error:

> Attribute
>   paths.'/api/v1/Product/MMSEventCallBack'(post).requestBody.content.encoding.contentType
>   is missing

This is code that is written in API - ASP.NET Core

```
[Route("MMSEventCallBack")]
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MmsEventCallBack([FromForm]MMSRequest mmsRequest)
{
    await _mmSFacade.ReceiveMMSEvent(mmsRequest);

    return Ok();
}
```

Am missing some kind of attribute in the above code? so it gives an error while adding it to Ready API.

Comment: **How** are you "trying to add an API in ReadyAPI"? Manually? WSDL? Swagger? ...?

Comment: @SiKing I am adding it through Swagger, There is an option in swagger for Json, I give its path.